# Elementary combinatorics: how many lunch salads?

Tags: combinatorics

Here is the problem: a restaurant offers salads with the following options: choose five ingredients from a list of eight, plus two dressings from a list of four, but do not choose radishes (one of the ingredients) with peanut butter dressing (you can have radishes without peanut butter dressing or peanut butter dressing without radishes, but not both). How many salads are possible?

I get (eight choose five) times (four choose two) minus (seven choose five) times (three choose two) or

$\frac{8!}{5!3!} \frac{4!}{2!2!} - \frac{7}{5!2!} \frac{3!}{2!1!}=273$

The text, Gerstien's Introduction to Mathematical Structures and Proofs, gives 231. Which is correct and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be subtracting the cases where you choose radishes and peanut butter dressing.  That leaves you only four vegetables to choose out of seven and one dressing to choose out of three, so it should be
$$\frac{8!}{5!3!} \frac{4!}{2!2!} - \frac{7}{4!3!} \frac{3!}{1!2!}=231$$

Answer (score 0):

All possible choices =${8\choose 5} × {4\choose 2}$

The case that is NOT allowed is radishes [always in](http://howtocombi.com/team-complex.html#inout1) AND peanut-butter [always in](http://howtocombi.com/team-complex.html#inout1).

Therefore you loose one choice from the salads and one choice from the dressing. The count:

${7\choose 4} × {3\choose 1}$

The final count:
${8\choose 5} × {4\choose 2} - {7\choose 4} × {3\choose 1} = 56 × 6 - 35 × 3 = 231$